# Attaching Multiple Files To An E-Mail From Database Image Column In .NET

Tags: c#, .net, database, email, attachment

are there any good examples of how to attach multiple files from a database to an e-mail in .NET?  I've got a method that returns a Byte[] containing the Image column contents that I am calling in a loop to get each attachment, but I was wondering if there was a "correct"/best-practice way of doing this, especially with the possibility of introducing memory leaks by using MemoryStreams to contain the data?  I'm fine creating en e-mail object and attaching the list of attachments to it, once I've got them and can do this fine with a single attachement but it seems to get slightly more complex with multiple files.  Considering I wouldn't have thought this was an unusual requirement, there seems to be a dearth of articles/posts about it.

Thx - MH

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how to proceed. Let's suppose that you have an array of attachments that you have loaded from your database:

```
IEnumerable<byte[]> attachments = ... fetch from your database
```

We could also safely assume that along with those attachments you have loaded the filenames and probably their corresponding MIME type (information that you surely must have persisted along with those byte arrays representing your attachments). So you will probably have fetched `IEnumerable<SomeAttachmentType>` but that's not important for the purpose of this post.

So now you could send the mail:

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.foo.com"))
using (var message = new MailMessage("from@foo.com", "to@bar.com"))
{
    message.Subject = "test subject";
    message.Body = "test body";
    message.IsBodyHtml = false;
    foreach (var attachment in attachments)
    {
        var attachmentStream = new MemoryStream(attachment);
        // TODO: Choose a better name for your attachments and adapt the MIME type
        var messageAttachment = new Attachment(attachmentStream, Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "application/octet-stream");
        message.Attachments.Add(messageAttachment);
    }
    client.Send(message);
}
```

Here's the deal:

A [`MailMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) (IDisposable) contains multiple [`Attachments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.aspx) (IDisposable). Each attachment references a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) (IDisposable). The MailMessage is wrapped in a using `block` which ensures that its Dispose method will be called which in turn calls the Dispose method of all attachments which in turn call the Dispose method of the memory streams.

Comment: I set my mail method up to accept attachment objects, rather than more specific streams from the database, but I might change this to reflect your suggestion.  I currently changed it to create an array of a custom object containing a list of memorystream and contenttype objects, then I create the attachments, pass them in and finally loop and dispose them all after the mail is sent. I'm in two minds, creating it your way makes it specific to getting the attachments from the DB, rather than a more generic send-mail-with-attachments method, but I don't think I'll want to send normal files

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can have buffered reads directly from the database, MemoryStream does NOT introduce any memory leak if you dispose it after usage. Example using SqlDataReader:

```
using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
  byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

  long l, dataOffset = 0;
  while ((l = reader.GetBytes(columnIndex, dataOffset, buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
  {
      stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
      dataOffset += l;
  }

  // here you have the whole stream and can attach it to the email...
}
```

similar question on how to read bytes from database has been asked already countless times, see here for example: [What is the most efficient way to read many bytes from SQL Server using SqlDataReader (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875450/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-read-many-bytes-from-sql-server-using-sqldatare)

Comment: What's the best way of using that single memory stream to read multiple files - if you have a loop around the using() {} section then you lose the contents of the files, even if you add then into the Attachemnts array within the using

Comment: @Mad, Darin's answer is more complete than mine and shows you everything, my solution is based on the assumption that you "copy" the stream's data into the attachment object.

Comment: Thanks - that works fine for one attachment, but I've found it doesn't work within a loop.  I think I need to record the start and end of each file so I can split them when reading, but that sounds possibly messy if it goes wrong, so I was aiming for one stream per file.  Thanks for the suggestion, it's always useful to hear several different solutions and you never know where else things will come in handy =8)